# How to check if list item is a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to add two lists together by using the zip function:

```
x = [2, 4]
y = [5, 7]
sum_list = [sum(x) for x in zip(list1, list2)]
> [7,11]
```

However, if the lists are comprised of strings I want to concatenate instead but the sum function doesn't work in this case.

```
x = ['a']
y = ['b']
return ['ab']
```

Is there a way to turn this into an if statement so that if x[0] = string, then concatenate instead of sum?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Simple

What about `+` operator ?

```
def concat_or_sum(list1, list2):
    return [x + y for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]

sum_list = concat_or_sum([2, 4], [5, 7])
print(sum_list)  # [7, 11]

sum_list = concat_or_sum(['a', 'c'], ['b', 'd'])
print(sum_list)  # ['ab', 'cd']
```

---

#### Improve

What about method version of `+` operator : `operator.add` ?

First solution is data-dependant, when changing the amount of lists, it requires to change also the code.

The solution is to apply `+` (using the `add` version) again and again on each value of the pairs

```
import operator
from functools import reduce

def concat_or_sum(*lists):
    return [reduce(operator.add, x) for x in zip(*lists)]

sum_list = concat_or_sum([2, 4, 't'], [5, 7, 't'], [10, 11, 't'])
print(sum_list)  # [17, 22, 'ttt']

sum_list = concat_or_sum([1, 'a', 'c'], [2, 'b', 'd'], [3, 'e', 'f'])
print(sum_list)  # [6, 'abe', 'cdf']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the if statement I came up with. You could tweak it to match your needs. Basically, just comparing the item with something you know is a string.

```
 a = "This is A"
    b = 1
    type_str = "Test"
def test_str(x):
    if type(x) == type(type_str):
        print("This is a string")
    elif type(x) != type(type_str):
        print("This is not a string")
test_str(a)
test_str(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` with `add` function-

```
from operator import add
x = [2, 4, 'a']
y = [5, 7, 'b']
sum_list = list(map(add, x, y))
```

Output -

```
[7, 11, 'ab']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import operator
from functools import reduce

list1 = [2, 4, 'a']
list2 = [5, 7, 'b']

sum_list = [reduce(operator.add, x) for x in zip(list1, list2)]

print(sum_list)  # [7, 11, 'ab']
```